# Drupal 7 Site Structure - Contextual Filters & View Path

Tags: views

I have a Drupal 7 website that is a resort guide.

I am now going to start adding further resorts to the site but I have a query regarding the site structure and how to use Views contextual filter well.

As we speak, the domain is set out for the one resort like as follows;

```
www.domain.com/[node-type:resort--title:resort-1]/[node-type:parent-category--title:hotels]/node:hotel]
www.domain.com/[node-type:resort--title:resort-1]/[node-type:parent-category--title:bars]/[node:bar]
www.domain.com/[node-type:resort--title:resort-1]/[node-type:parent-category--title:restaurants]/[node:restaurant]
```

On the **[node-type:parent-category]** I use a block created through Views to display a masonry grid for each of the nodes that are tagged with that category ie a masonry display of bars

I am now wanting to use views and panels to display all the relevant information using contextual filers but because I have a node for that particular resort as the parent, I cant use a contextual filters.

So what I am adopting is setting out the new resorts as follows;

```
www.domain.com/resort/[views:page-contextual-filter:term:resort]/[views:page-contextual-filter:term:category]/
```

Is this the correct way to implement the site? Or could you suggest a better way. I have asked this a few places and got no response, remember we was all beginners like me at one point, help me out if you can.

Thank you!